# Can IBM WebSphere 8 by default handle https?

Tags: ssl, websphere, websphere-8

I realize this could be a very newbie question since I don't have enough knowledge of httpserver/appserver/ssl.

The thing is I don't have a standalone IBM HTTP Server, I only have IBM WebSphere 8.5 installed. I can access my app via http but not via https(port 9443).

I can see that IBM is listening on port 9443, which I think is for the https.

I googled this, but seems people are all talking about the configuration of IBM HTTP Server.

Is it possible to enable https in this case, if so, what extra configurations should I do?

Comment: You shouldn't have any issues accessing https port. What error do you get? Maybe your browser is blocking self sign WebSphere certificate.

Comment: @Gas actually this is an app which exposes some REST APIs, I was testing these APIs via Advanced REST Client.

Comment: You should have DefaultApplication installed, so you can always test on the `https://host:9443/snoop` to see if it is displayed.

Comment: Thank you @Gas I can access this site although there's warning on the url bar, seems like it's a problem of Advanced REST Client, I can successfully call these APIs using curl on command line.

Comment: @Gas I would like to select your comment as the answer, how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't have any issues accessing https port. What error do you get? Maybe your browser is blocking self sign WebSphere certificate. For testing https you can use  DefaultApplication which is installed by default and try to access snoop servlet - `https://host:9443/snoop`